# Is there any way to prevent out of memory from owncloud?

Tags: php, linux, process, out-of-memory, owncloud

I have a owncloud in a Ubuntu with 5,3 GB RAM.

Every day I have a "out-of-memory" which kills mysql process and owncloud website fails. So I've to restart that server (dedicate to owncloud) every day at least one time (not a good practice...)

This is a `px aux --sort -pmem |more` ;

[image]

There are more than 50 process like *files:scan -all*.They increase continuously until OOM.

I read something about OCC but I can't get how to disable.

I try to edit mpm_prefork.conf and set;

[image]

Also read about edit overcommit_memory and set disable, but I don't want a kernel panic too.

Every process uses about 1.1% Memory. In a few hours get 100% and kernel kills MySQL and other process.

Any idea/solution?

Comment: And what does `console.php` actually do?

Comment: Check if there is any error message under `Settings > (Administration) Basic settings > Background jobs` in the app menu. That multiple and endless `occ files:scan -all` spawning processes is definitely a missbehaviour and should not be happening.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz This is the content; https://pastebin.com/TGbStW5i

Comment: @hads0m https://i.imgur.com/ymwH2Ax.png and https://i.imgur.com/9W4Ingg.png

Comment: Well, I would start by fixing all those error messages coming up... Specially that one saying something about file integrity. I'm sure that will definitely have something to do with those `occ file:scan -all` processes...

Comment: Okay, I found this commad @hads0m; https://i.imgur.com/yM9DKdD.png , its running

Comment: line 67 - `set_time_limit(0)` - remove this or reduce it..

Comment: Y comment to; //set_time_limit(0) https://i.imgur.com/Hm7eCTC.png
,But still creating process,and OOM, and killing mysql/php https://i.imgur.com/nLbXdEl.png

Comment: I update to 10.2 a few minutes ago, but still creating process; https://i.imgur.com/LJ7Lbad.png

Comment: What Could be happen if i delete console.php?

Comment: Are you still having this problem? How many users do you have? It may not be a good idea to run the cron in AJAX mode on a large installation. It's probably the cron triggering the file scan, and the scan is not completing in time. On a large installation you want to run everything from a manual crontab, and make sure the file scan has time to complete. I recommend disabling the cron and running the file scan once manually to make sure it completes.